# Replace 1 newline with <br>, >= 2 with <br><br>

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I use the following to replace every linebreak with a `<br>`:

```
h(my_string).gsub(/(?:\n\r?|\r\n?)/, '<br>').html_safe
```

I wonder if there would be any solution where if there's a single linebreak, then replace it with a single `<br>`. And if there are two or more linebreaks, then replace all with only two `<br>`, i.e. `<br><br>`?

Comment: Not exactely the answer to your question, but Rails' [simple_format](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/simple_format) deals exactely with these problems. Perhaps that's the better approach for you.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's not true that it handles it as described in the question. [According to the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format): "Two or more consecutive newlines(\n\n) are considered as a paragraph and wrapped in <p> tags. One newline (\n) is considered as a linebreak and a <br /> tag is appended."

Comment: I didn't say it handles it as described in the question, just that it deals with these problems. And normally a new paragraph makes more sense than two linebreaks, so I wanted to suggest it. Sorry to bother you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate couple of times

```
h(my_string).gsub(/(\n\r?){2,}/, '<br><br>').gsub(/\n/, '<br>').html_safe
```

Comment: Doesn't work. 5 newlines results in 5 `<br>`. Sidenote: you need to append `.html_safe` to parse it as html and not as a string.

Comment: @FellowStranger forgot to add \r. Updated the answer. And thanks for the side note, was too focused on code that replaces newlines :)